# Email temporary password

Tags: python, django

Hello I am new to django and web programming. I am building a website for my school that allows students to schedule online advising appointments.

I need to be able to email students temporary passcodes to their student emails and then validate them on the next page. I have an email form :

```
    class EmailForm(forms.Form):
    student_email = forms.EmailField(max_length = 200, label = 'Mail')
    def clean_student_email(self):
        student_email = self.cleaned_data['student_email']
        if not student_email.endswith('.edu'):
                raise ValidationError("Please enter your school email that ends with @edu")
        return student_email
```

and a login view

```
    def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EmailForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            student_email = form.cleaned_data['student_email']
            random_code = get_random_string()
            subject = "Temporary Advising Code"
            message = f'Your temporary code is: \n code: {random_code}'
            send_mail(subject, message, 'advising email', [student_email])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/enter_code/', {'form' : form})
        
    else:
        form = EmailForm()
    return render(request, 'login/login.html', {'form' : form})
```

Now I am able to generate a random string and send it to the students email but I am wondering if someone can tell me how I can validate that string on the next page.

Comment: You store it in a model, so in the database?

Comment: I'm not storing it in a model, I don't need to make a user for the student. This is just purely to verify that the person scheduling an appointment is a student at our school.

Comment: you do not need to store it in the `Student` model, etc. but if you want to *persist* data, you need to store it in the database.

Comment: Ok so the only way to do it would be to store the temporary password in the database? There's no way to do it by returning the form context {'form' : form} with the HttpResponseRedirect ?

Answer (score 0):

I would advice against your approach.

But I would suggest to check how password reset token generator works in django .

Source: [PasswordResetTokenGenerator](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/tokens.py)

You can make something very similar to generate a token which you will send to students.

You don't need to store such token as you can easily generate it again ( when it comes to verification ).

So the idea here is to generate the token using some data which after password is changed or set by students - the token will no longer be valid.

You can even incorporate a expiration time if needed.

And you don't need to generate temporary password either ( which is something i don't like very much ).

So instead of sending students the  temp password and asking them to log in with that -  you would  just send them a link with the token and by accessing the page with that token - they will be able to set a password.

Comment: Ya I know I named my view badly because I'm not actually logging in users. All I want to do is send a student a random string to their student emails. Then on the next page I want them to enter that code. I don't have or want to make student users. I just want to verify that the person trying to access the advising form is a student at our school. I can currently send the email with the code but I do not know how to verify that code on the next page.

Comment: Not quite sure what is exactly your use case. But the token generation like it is done in the reset token generator will give you idea how to generate a token which you dont need to store and you can still validate. If your use case is a form which you want student to fill and send - you can send them the token with a link to the page, so on accessing the page, you will put that token in a hidden field and on submit - you will validate - if incorrect, you just reject the submission. If you have other case - just adjust.